# how to specify loc type in sitemap.xml?

Tags: xml, web, sitemap.xml

hello I want to specify all URL if it is category, product or static page, how can I achieve it inside sitemap ?
I searched it for hours and I could not find any solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The format doesn't have any concept of those categories of pages.

The closest is [the `<changefreq>` element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps#File_format) which lets you say that a static page changes infrequently.